# sql function to convert string to epoch but without using timestamp type in between

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

in postgres (actually redshift - see [redshift immutable varchar to timestamp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74903665/redshift-immutable-varchar-to-timestamp-function)) I'm looking for a SQL based (not python or other) UDF function to convert string to epoch int. BUT key point is that it cannot make use of any intermediate functions that convert to/from timestamp. So I guess the only way is to count seconds since 1970 by multiplying days in year (accounting for leap years. ie 365+365+365+366+365+....+31+28+31+30....+17+...)

```
input string value=2017-08-18 11:59:30.345


desired output int value=1503057570345
```

Comment: what is the reason why you can't use any intermediate functions that convert to/from timestamp ?

Comment: @Edouard redshift 'auto MatViews' prevent 'mutable' functions

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the past to implement that function, but I never get the same result as EPOCH maybe because of the bisextile years of for some other complex reasons.

There may be a workaround to create an immutable version of EPOCH :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION epoch_immutable(val varchar)
RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE val) ; $$ ;
```

The function `epoch_immutable` can be used in an index because it is immutable, whereas the function `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` cannot.

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ot8WNEJ5)

Comment: did u try with redshift?

Comment: no I didn't test it on redshift, only on postgres with index which do not accept non immutable functions as demonstrated in dbfiddle

Comment: redshift says its mutable